# distinctUntilChanged: Old value is alway null

Tags: redux, rxjs

I'm bad at introductions, so let's just cut right to the chase:

I am getting an observable from a redux store by using `ngRedux.select`. Immediately after I use a pipe with `distinctUntilChanged` with a custom compare function. However, inside this function the old value is always `null`, no matter how often it is being called.

Also when I put the `distinctUntilChanged` at a later point in the pipe after some parsing (which was the original plan), it will again always return the same value: The first one that came through the observable. Somehow I feel I am completely misunderstanding this operator, but I am using it the way the documentation suggests.

Here's the complete code I am using:

```
this.ngRedux.select((store: RootDomain) => getValue(() => {
  const localContext = store.core.context[contextUuid];
  const globalContext = store.core.context[GLOBAL_CONTEXT_KEY];
  const context = Object.assign({}, globalContext, localContext);
  return context[key];
})).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((x, y) => {
    console.log('OLD: ', x);
    console.log('NEW: ', y);
    return isEqual(x, y);
  })
);
```

I also tried simply returning true all the time to see if anything would change (of course it didn't). `x` will always log as `null` here. Please help me understand this operator!

Comment: What you are doing with `distinctUntilChanged` looks okay to me. Are you sure your logic inside of `isEqual()` is behaving as expected?

Comment: It's from lodash, so I'd hope it works.

Comment: The `distinctUntilChanged` is used correctly here, problem lies with your usage of the Observable that is created as a result of ngRedux.select. Can you show us where and how are you using it?

Comment: I have just bumped into that issue. Any ideas why prev values is always null

Comment: @Antoniossss Sorry, no clue. I ended up implementing it in a completely different way. In other instances `distinctUntilChanged` actually worked fine, but it wouldn't work on this example.